# Rails have ActiveRecord grab more than one association in one go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The question below had a good answer to grab associated values of an activerecord collection in one hit using `Comment.includes(:user)`. What about when you have multiple associations that you want to grab in one go?

[Rails have activerecord grab all needed associations in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722632/rails-have-activerecord-grab-all-needed-associations-in-one-go)

Is the best way to just chain these together like below `Customer.includes(:user).includes(:sales).includes(:prices)` or is there a cleaner way.

Furthermore, when I am doing this on a loop on an index table. Can I add a method on the `customer.rb` model so that I can call `@customers.table_includes` etc and have

```
def table_includes
  self.includes(:user).includes(:sales).includes(:prices)
end
```

For the record I tested the above and it didn't work because its a method on a collection (yet to figure out how to do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answering this, I'm assuming that `user`, `sales`, and `prices` are all associations off of `Customer`.

Instead of chaining, you can do something like this:

```
Customer.includes(:user, :sales, :prices)
```

In terms of creating an abstraction for this, you do have a couple options.

First, you could create a scope:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :table_includes, -> { includes(:user, :sales, :prices) }
end
```

Or if you want for it to be a method, you should consider making it a class-level method instead of an instance-level one:

```
def self.table_includes
  self.includes(:user, :sales, :prices)
end
```

I would consider the purpose of creating this abstraction though. A very generic name like `table_includes` will likely not be very friendly over the long term.

Comment: Thank you. I included this as a scope and has worked really well. I have includes so that I wasn't calling the database on each loop. Seems with `joins` it is going back to querying the database. Is there a way to joins and includes at the same time or just chain that aswell in the scope?

Comment: And 'yes' to your assumption that the tables are activerecord associates with has_many and belongs_to etc.

Comment: So far using `scope :table_includes, -> { joins(:user, :sales, :prices).includes(:user, :sales, :prices) }` seems to work but not very dry. Hoping there is something I can substitute for `joins` and `includes` in one call.

Comment: I guess `joins` doesn't make much sense if you're joining several tables off of the same table. (Sorry, wasn't thinking clearly enough.) That would create a recordset that repeats many of the rows unnecessarily. I'd keep it at `includes` to eager load each association separately. That's probably as good as you're going to get.

Comment: (Editing the answer to reflect that.)

Comment: Cheers. Ill stick with includes then. Also maybe rename it to `includes_for_table_partial` possible even put that in a decorator instead as it is to do with the view. Thanks again